# Creating jinja widget

Tags: python, jinja2

I need some help to get to the right directions about jinja templates.
Let's say I have successfully created a route and template using bokeh like this :

```
import flask_bcrypt
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import INLINE


bokeh = Blueprint('bokeh', __name__, template_folder="templates")


@bokeh.route('/bokeh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bokeh_main():

   

    fig = figure(plot_width=800,
                 plot_height=600,

                 x_axis_label='x',
                 y_axis_label='y')
    hover = fig.select(dict(type=HoverTool))

    # tooltips =
    fig.line(
        legend_label="Random numbers.",
        x=[1, 2, 3, 10],
        y=[1.7, 2.2, 4.6, 3.9],

    )
    hover = HoverTool(mode="vline")
    hover.tooltips=[
        ('random-number', '@x'),
        ('random-result', '@y')
    ]
    fig.tools.append(hover)

    # grab the static resources
    js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
    css_resources = INLINE.render_css()




    script, div = components(fig)

    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        js_resources=js_resources,
        css_resources=css_resources,
    )
```

however, I want to reuse this chart route result on let say sales report route, or whatever other route.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract the figure resource creation into a helper-function, like this:

```py
def create_figure_resources():
    fig = figure(plot_width=800,
                 plot_height=600,

                 x_axis_label='x',
                 y_axis_label='y')
    hover = fig.select(dict(type=HoverTool))

    # tooltips =
    fig.line(
        legend_label="Random numbers.",
        x=[1, 2, 3, 10],
        y=[1.7, 2.2, 4.6, 3.9],

    )
    hover = HoverTool(mode="vline")
    hover.tooltips=[
        ('random-number', '@x'),
        ('random-result', '@y')
    ]
    fig.tools.append(hover)

    js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
    css_resources = INLINE.render_css()
    script, div = components(fig)

    return {
        "js_resources": js_resources,
        "css_resources": css_resources,
        "script": script,
        "div": div,
    }
```

Then, you can just call that function from different routes to generate the figure resources:

```py
@bokeh.route('/bokeh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bokeh_main():
    figure_resources = create_figure_resources()
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        plot_script=figure_resources["script"],
        plot_div=figure_resources["div"],
        js_resources=figure_resources["js_resources"],
        css_resources=figure_resources["css_resources"],
    )


@bokeh.route('/sales', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bokeh_sales():
    figure_resources = create_figure_resources()
    return render_template(
        'sales.html',
        plot_script=figure_resources["script"],
        plot_div=figure_resources["div"],
        js_resources=figure_resources["js_resources"],
        css_resources=figure_resources["css_resources"],
    )
```